# How to display List items in Listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView in my aspx file like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"></asp:ListView>
```

and then I have List like this:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
```

Im trying to populate the ListView like so:

```
foreach(string elem in mylist)
{
  ListView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(elem));
}
```

But my compiler is telling me best overload match error & cannot convert string to ListViewItem.  This is a asp.net 4.0 web app.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try binding your ListView like the following:

code-behind

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>() { "stealthy", "ninja", "panda"};
listView.DataSource = mylist;
listView.DataBind();
```

aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="<%#Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `ListView`, you should be able to bind the data to the `DataSource` of the control:

```
ListView1.DataSource = myList;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

[ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx) does not have any constructor that takes a string. 
Also [ListView.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.items.aspx) is an `IList<ListViewDataItem>` not a collection of `ListViewItem`

You probably want to use databinding rather than iteratively adding items anyway.

Comment: It's easy to confuse the web control with the forms control of the same name (which does provide a constructor that takes a string)