# How do i display database files from a selected drive on listview C# winforms ?

Tags: c#

How am i able to display '.mdf' extensions or all database file extensions and it's size on a listview from a selected drive such as 'C:' or 'D:' in C# ? ..

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this MSDN article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx
It will help you in traversing through directories and files.

This article will give you details about displaying ListView from a list of items. [How to display List items in Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935931/how-to-display-list-items-in-listview)

Find out appropriate APIs for you, and report if you get stuck anywhere. Somebody will be able to help you with your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Most efficient way to find all XYZ files on disk using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965388/495455)

Then to get the filesize just use the `FileInfo` class. For more file info you can [GetSpecificFileProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660616/495455).